# How to manage many icons in React properly?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components, icons

I have multiple Icon components like this:

```
import { IconProps } from "@utils/types";

const FilterIcon = (props: IconProps) => {
  const { fillColor, width, height } = props;

  return (
    <svg
      width={width}
      height={height}
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      fill="white"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <path
        d="M17.625 12C1..."
        fill={fillColor}
      />
    </svg>
  );
};

export default FilterIcon;
```

the problem is that I have almots 40 of them in different files. I want to make a component to use them in a better way, something like this:

```
<Icon name="IconName" width="20px" height="20px" fillColor="white" />
```

where name could be an enum type or similar

I made a huge Icon component that imports all the icons and uses a switch to return an icon component (130 lines...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can declare a barrel file:

```
// icons/index.ts
export { default as FilterIcon } from './FilterIcon.tsx'
// ...
```

And then create an `<Icon>` component:

```
// icon.tsx
import * as icons from './icons'

export const Icon = ({ name, ...props }: {
  name: keyof typeof icons,
  // other props
}) => {
  const Component = icons[name]
  return <Component {...props} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a switch statement, you can utilize a mapping object to map icon names to their respective components.

```
import React from 'react';
import { IconProps } from '@utils/types';
import FilterIcon from './FilterIcon'; // Import your individual icon components

// Map icon names to their respective components
const iconComponents: Record<string, React.FC<IconProps>> = {
  FilterIcon,
  // Add more icons here as needed
};

type IconName = keyof typeof iconComponents;

interface Props extends Omit<IconProps, 'fillColor'> {
  name: IconName;
  fillColor?: string;
}

const Icon: React.FC<Props> = ({ name, fillColor = 'white', ...rest }) => {
  const IconComponent = iconComponents[name];

  if (!IconComponent) {
    console.error(`Icon component "${name}" not found.`);
    return null;
  }

  return <IconComponent {...rest} fillColor={fillColor} />;
};

export default Icon;
```

and then you can use like below:-

```
<Icon name="FilterIcon" width="20px" height="20px" fillColor="white" />
```